# Mongo document is lacking the shard key property

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am aware of what does it mean by "Sharding". 
However, i do not know how do I include the Shard key in a mongo document.
please share an example.

Answer (score 0):

Shard key of a collection can be an existing key or you can create a separate unique key for in your document specifically for the sharding.

In any case, you need to choose a shard key with some specific attributes: Please refer more here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#choosing-a-shard-key

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/limits/#limits-shard-keys

(If you are not quite sure what needs to be the shard key, auto-generated _id of the collection will be a good starting point.)